# Re-using Chronicle Bytes' OutputStream

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-bytes

I'm utilizing a third party binary encoder that takes an OutputStream.  I retrieve the OutputStream from a Marshallable's writeMarshallable method similar to this:

```
public void writeMarshallable(WireOut wire) {
    OutputStream outputStream = wire.bytes().outputStream();
    // third party code gets the outputStream, etc.
}
```

*wire.bytes().outputStream()*'s implementation creates a new StreamingOutputStream on each invocation, which is what I'm hoping to avoid (superfluous object allocation when the underlying Bytes *hasn't actually changed*).

That said, I'm thinking about storing a WeakReference to the given wire.bytes() value and checking to see if the provided value reference (ie, ==) is identical to the previously provided value:

```
private WeakReference<Bytes<?>> priorBytesRef = new WeakReference<>(null);

public void writeMarshallable(WireOut wire) {
    Bytes<?> bytes = wire.bytes();
    if (bytes != priorBytesRef.get()) {
        priorBytesRef = new WeakReference<>(bytes);
        thirdPartyEncoder = EncoderFactoryExample.from(bytes.outputStream());
    }
    // utilize thirdPartyEncoder, etc.
}
```

So my question is whether this is a reasonable approach or if you Chronicle folks have a more advisable way?

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a ThreadLocal to save a `StreamingOutputStream`.

```
static final ThreadLocal<StreamingOutputStream> bosTL = ThreadLocal.withInitial(StreamingOutputStream::new);

public void writeMarshallable(WireOut wire) {
    OutputStream out = bosTL.get().init(wire.bytes());
    // utilize thirdPartyEncoder, etc.
}
```

Comment: If the Marshallable's allocation is by way of a ServiceWrapper (ie, it's a _single_ allocation managed by the ServiceWrapper), is the ThreadLocal necessary or can I just get away with a BytesOutputStream _class member_?  Thanks again, Pete!

Comment: @A.Oswald The ThreadLocal is only needed if you can't be sure only one thread will be using the stream.

Comment: Unless I've got either versioning or dependency goofed up, I'm afraid there's a conflict of Bytes _type_ being provided by Chronicle-Queue (net.openhft.chronicle.bytes) vs what BytesOutputStream's api requires (net.openhft.lang.io).  I was getting BytesOutputStream from OpenHFT/Java-Lang (v 6.8.2).

Comment: Pete: **code does not compile**; please see my above comment regarding Bytes type incompatibility.  Any thoughts?  thanks

Comment: @A.Oswald I suggest avoiding Java-Lang as this is an older library. I suggest using Chronicle-Bytes which is what Chronicle-Queue uses.

Comment: At first I felt a bit foolish, but after checking, BytesOutputStream (currently) _does not exist_ in **Chronicle-Bytes**.  Can you please double check this?

Comment: @A.Oswald Sorry, that is my mistake, you are right, the class was renamed. Can you check out the latest snapshot for `StreamingOutputStream`. If you are happy with that I can release it.

Comment: Are you suggesting calling StreamingOutputStream's _init_ on each invocation? I'm not terribly fond of the method name, but everything else appears to look good (and I don't have a better suggestion).  Thanks for looking into this! Ps: the code example will need to change from _bytes_ to whatever you end up calling it (currently _init_)

Comment: @A.Oswald Yes, thank you for the correction. I use `init` as this is the name for constructors, at the byte code level constructors are called `<init>`